# Curl extension is enable, but composer still showing the extension isn't enable yet

Tags: php, laravel, curl, composer-php

Already manually enable the curl in the "php.ini" at the location of "etc/php/8.2/apache2"

[image]

But the composer still showing the extension was not enabled yet.

[image]

I have already tried restarting apache2 services and reloading it. But the composer still showing that curl has not enable yet. I am still a beginner so any kind of help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `etc/php/8.2/apache2`...that's the location for the ini file for the webserver. Command-line PHP generally has a separate ini file

Comment: running `php -i` from the command line should tell you the location

Comment: From your installation it looks like you're using Ubuntu/Linux. Try installing deps using the : `sudo apt-get install php-curl`. That would do the job for you.

Comment: @ADyson when i edit the php.ini files in "cli" folder, it return this error message when trying to use composer command again "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/curl (/usr/lib/php/20220829/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/curl.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Ok so...did you actually install the extension too, as Sachin mentioned? You can enable the extension in the configuration, but unless it's actually physically there (which the error message suggests it isn't), then obviously it still won't do anything.

Comment: I just did what Sachin suggested and now the warning message is gone. Thanks for the help.